# Find difference of two time in sql query

Tags: sql-server

I have One Table DailyPerformanceReport(with Two Time Columns) with data like this in SQL Server 2008R2

[image: Table]

i want to get difference of InPunch and OutPunch as WorkHRs(in Time format).Myexpected output 
[image]

Comment: What are data types of In and Out fields?

Comment: Both fields are of  time(7) data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
CREATE TABLE DailyPerformanceReport(
    InPunch     TIME,
    OutPunch    TIME
)
INSERT INTO DailyPerformanceReport VALUES
('09:14:00', '19:22:00'),
('09:54:00', '19:37:00'),
('09:14:00', '18:39:00');
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT
    *,
    WorkHRS = CAST(DATEADD(MILLISECOND, DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, InPunch, OutPunch), 0) AS TIME)
FROM DailyPerformanceReport
```

**RESULT**

```
InPunch          OutPunch         WorkHRS
---------------- ---------------- ----------------
09:14:00.0000000 19:22:00.0000000 10:08:00.0000000
09:54:00.0000000 19:37:00.0000000 09:43:00.0000000
09:14:00.0000000 18:39:00.0000000 09:25:00.0000000
```

Comment: why you are not using Convert Function instead of Cast Function...  SELECT CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,InPunch,OutPunch),0)) FROM DailyPerformancereport

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the [datediff](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp) functionality.

```
select DATEDIFF(MINUTE ,'value1',DateAdd(day, 1, 'value2'))
```